# Override method from gem package in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the [package](https://github.com/umts/prawn-rails-forms) and initialise it in my rails application in config/initializers/prawn_rails.rb with `include PrawnRailsForms`

I am trying to override a [method](https://github.com/umts/prawn-rails-forms/blob/master/lib/prawn-rails-forms/document_extensions.rb#L68) to increase the font size of field.upcase with the code below

```
include PrawnRailsForms

DocumentExtensions.module_eval do
  def make_field_box(field)
    stroke_bounds
    bounds.add_left_padding 2
    move_down 2
    text field.upcase, size: 18
  end
end
```

But the font doesn't get affected in the pdf views even I restarted the server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the [monkey pathing](https://www.culttt.com/2015/06/17/what-is-monkey-patching-in-ruby) here.

1. Create a `prawn-rails-forms` directory in `lib` directory.
2. Create a `document_extensions.rb` file inside `prawn-rails-forms` directory.
3. Add below code to the `document_extensions.rb`

   ```
   module PrawnRailsForms
     module DocumentExtensions

       private

       def make_field_box(field)
         stroke_bounds
         bounds.add_left_padding 2
         move_down 2
         text field.upcase, size: 8
       end
     end
   end
   ```
4. Restart the server.

**Extended**

If you find still not working after restarting the server then

- Add `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` to the `config/application.rb` OR
- Move `prawn-rails-forms` directory to the `config/initializers`

Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I did that. It doesn't work at first, but I actually have to include the whole DocumentExtensions to make it work. Turns out that some functions that are using this make_field_box have to be patched too.